# How to include jQuery SVG source in SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Is it possible to include [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) source code in a standalone SVG document? I mean like:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    <![CDATA[
        // jQuery SVG code
    ]]>
</script>
```

I need the SVG document to be independent of other files. (copy it elsewhere and it will work without any other files, internet connection,...)
Trying so, I get:

> error on line 383 at column 16623: StartTag: invalid element name

Which is:

```
b='<'+a.nodeName;
```

How to make it seem as a string, not a start tag?
I'm unable to make it work by commenting out CDATA parts or the script as whole (I have tried //, /* */ and `<!-- -->`). I guess I'm missing something simple here...

Here is an example SVG document with a simple JS script with jQuery 1.6.4 and jQuery SVG 1.4.4 source codes: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5552845/test.svg
Note: moving jQuery SVG source code out will lead to perfectly working SVG document

Comment: try escaping it `b='\\<'+a.nodeName;`

Comment: There's really no reason to use CDATA blocks around JavaScript anymore. Maybe in 1998 it was useful, but not now. (I guess unless you're using XHTML for some reason, but there's no reason to do that either :-)

Comment: Using amp codes?  `&lt;` for <

Comment: @3nigma Escaping makes no difference, I don't understand why...?

Comment: @Pointy Deleting CDATA makes browser complain "error on line 382 at column 370: xmlParseEntityRef: no name" which points at &

Comment: @jbrookover Amp code doesn't help either. Returns "error on line 383 at column 16689: error parsing attribute name". (it points at semicolon, eh)

Comment: Ah - your `<script>` tag is embedded in the SVG - I get it now.  I can imagine that'd cause weirdness, but in the same sense I'm not sure that a script block in some SVG code will even work at all. I suppose that's basically your question :-)

Comment: @Pointy Exactly! :) 
I've just realized, it works for jQuery source code without any hacks. So there should be some way.

Comment: Have you tried `b = '\u003C' + a.nodeName;` ?

Comment: @Pointy Pretty good idea! Didn't occur to me. However, not working mystically. :/ It says: "error on line 20 at column 16691: error parsing attribute name" (strangely on a variable 'a' from your comment)

Comment: What is it that you're using to view this document?  Firefox? Chrome? Something else?

Comment: Up-to-date FF, Opera and Chrome. All of them report an error on the same line/column (Opera is one char to the left).

Comment: @Pointy SVG in XHTML is a very valid use case, and CDATA blocks are entirely appropriate within XHTML (unless you want your `<` and `&&` in JS code to break everything). Further, when SVG is not in HTML or XHTML, but standalone, it is itself an XML application and again the CDATA block is completely necessary.

Comment: @xius Making it a CDATA block is all you should need to do. Can you please provide a [pastie](http://pastie.org) of your SVG file with the JS in there, or host the file somewhere for us to debug?

Comment: @Phrogz yes I finally figured that out in the 7th comment :-)

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks for interest. I'll edit question to include a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery SVG includes the string ']]>', which ends the cdata block.

If you change ']]>' to ']'+']>' the file becomes valid.

see http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3885046/test.svg

Comment: Whoa, thank you enormously! I've never noticed the issue lies there.